# Web Scrape with Python Requests gives 401 error

Tags: python, web-scraping, web, python-requests

Some code I've been using for a while to scrape financial data from the Wall Street Journal has just ceased to work and now runs with a 401 error.

I've tried changing the header but this didn't work. Perhaps I now need a login?

```
import requests
url='https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/bond/JP/TMBMKJP-01Y?mod=quote_search'
headers =  {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11;Linux x86_64;rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'}
page=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print('Page status code',page.status_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the WSJ has put a captcha in the way, probably as an anti-scrape measure. Obtaining API credentials is probably the way around this. At least it's worth looking into.

Take a look at the content returned:

```py
import requests
url='https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/bond/JP/TMBMKJP-01Y?mod=quote_search'
headers =  {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11;Linux x86_64;rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'}
page=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print('Page status code',page.content)
```

Content:

```html
Page status code b'<html><head><title>wsj.com</title><style>#cmsg{animation: A 1.5s;}@keyframes A{0%{opacity:0;}99%{opacity:0;}100%{opacity:1;}}</style></head><body style="margin:0"><p id="cmsg">Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker</p><script data-cfasync="false">var dd={\'rt\':\'c\',\'cid\':\'AHrlqAAAAAMArpN2vLo4VCUAMhA_Hw==\',\'hsh\':\'D428D51E28968797BC27FB9153435D\',\'t\':\'fe\',\'s\':47129,\'e\':\'e92911034aa65357785f6313394521ae3cbda7ac3d302f1fdd231820f33c85a6\',\'host\':\'geo.captcha-delivery.com\'}</script><script data-cfasync="false" src="https://ct.captcha-delivery.com/c.js"></script></body></html>\n'
```

Comment: Thanks, I now see that WSJ has a developer platform, so that's probably the way to go. I did create a WSJ login and used that in the get request but it didn't help.

Comment: Thanks for the update; I was hoping that would do the trick. (I use the NYT API and thought WSJ would have a similar developer's API) Hopefully the Docs on the WSJ developer's portal can be helpful. If not, you may want to try the 'yfinance' Python module. I use that to get stocks information. Though I know what a hassle it is to switch from something that had worked to a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i think you should try it with credentials, if the returned status code is 403 that's mean you're unauthorized, good luck :)

Comment: This is just reaffirming @j-adam’s much more detailed answer.